# SQL "group by" doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

**If there is follwing table:**

```
offer(title, price, theater)
```

The purpose of this table is to describe theaters that offer their movies at their prices.

**What I want to show is that:**

> for each movie, show its price that is offered at highest price by one
>   of all theaters, also shows theater name that offers it at highest
>   price.

**So here, I wrote:**

```
select A.movie, max(A.price), A.theater from offer A group by A.movie
```

However, this doesn't work. How can I show distinct title along with its price and theater that offers it at highest prices among all the theaters?

Comment: you cannot have a column in select clause if it is not present in group by.

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.  If your query fails to run, then you are probably using Oracle (why I removed the MySQL tag).  You should explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I believe the user is using MySql and not Oracle and the `Oracle` tag should have been removed instead since my answer worked for him and it is not a syntax valid for Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can write the query to find the highest price and its corresponding theatre:

```
SELECT o.movie,
       (
            SELECT MAX(price)
            FROM offer
            WHERE movie = o.movie
       ) as price,
       (
            SELECT theater
            FROM offer
            WHERE movie = o.movie
            ORDER BY price DESC
            LIMIT 1
       ) as theater
FROM offer o;
```

Comment: Do you know meaning of DESC LIMIT 1? I have never seen such query before. Thank you very much.

Comment: `ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1` = sort rows by highest price and take one only

Comment: Limit 1 is not valid oracle syntax.

Comment: @BobC, at the time I answered, the question had the tag `MySQL` and @Gordon Linoff removed it since. I think the user is using MySQL since it worked for him. I am pretty sure the `Oracle` tag should have been removed by Gordon instead

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.movie, A.theater, max(A.price)
from offer A
 group by A.movie,  A.theater
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to do this uses `row_number()`:

```
select o.movie, o.price, o.theater
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by movie order by price desc) as seqnum
      from offer o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that you can do this without a subquery in Oracle:

```
select movie, max(price),
       max(theater) keep (dense_rank first order by price desc) as theater
from offer o
order by movie;
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that offer table, just has

> title, price and theater

Columns.

If you didn't make an error by writing the question, the problem is that the column movie doesn't exists